# Shell script continues to run even after exit command

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

My shell script is as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure only root can run our script
[ $EUID -ne 0 ] && (echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2) || (exit 1)

# other script continues here...
```

When I run above script with non-root user, it prints message "This script..." but it doe not exit there, it continues with the remaining script. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I don't want to use if condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running  `echo` and `exit` in subshells. The exit call will only leave that subshell, which is a bit pointless.

Try with:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
echo hello
```

If for some reason you don't want an `if` condition, just use:

```
#! /bin/sh
[ $EUID -ne 0 ] && echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2 && exit 1
echo hello
```

Note: no `()` and fixed boolean condition. Warning: if `echo` fails, that test will also fail to exit. The `if` version is safer (and more readable, easier to maintain IMO).

Comment: Edited, although I don't understand why you'd want to avoid the `if`.

Comment: @Mat, at least with `bash`, the return value of `echo` is always 0.

Comment: @paxdiablo: POSIX allows [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) to fail. Not sure how/when though, and that's not something I'd worry about too much - not sure what you can do to recover from a failed echo...

Comment: POSIX may (it may fail if you're redirecting to a device that fills up), but the bash_builtins man page specifically disallows that. Not that it matters, this shouldn't be happening in one line anyway. I much prefer your multi-line version :-)

Comment: Why the $*#% don't you want to use an `if`?  This is exactly what `if` is for.  (You can write an `if` on one line if you value terseness over legibility.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `&&` rather than`||`, since you want to echo *and* exit (not echo *or* exit).

In addition `(exit 1)` will run a sub-shell that exits rather than exiting your current shell.

The following script shows what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $1 -ne 0 ] && (echo "This script must be run as root." 1>&2) && exit 1
echo Continuing...
```

Running this with `./myscript 0` gives you:

```
Continuing...
```

while `./myscript 1` gives you:

```
This script must be run as root.
```

I believe that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would write that as:

```
(( $EUID != 0 )) && { echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2; exit 1; }
```

Using `{ }` for grouping, which executes in the current shell. Note that the spaces around the braces and the ending semi-colon are required.