# exit within single line

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q 'string1' abc.txt && sed -i~ "s/string1/string2/g" abc.txt || echo "ERROR1! Exiting..."; exit
grep -q 'string2' pqr.txt && sed -i~ "s/string2/string3/g" pqr.txt || echo "ERROR2! Exiting..."; exit

#...Several similar above commands here...
```

In above script, when string1 is present, it replaces with string2 but then it exits. I want the script to execute the next command. It should exit only when it doesn't find string1...

How can I do that here? I don't want to use if conditions...

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know alternate ways especially doing in single line...

Comment: You want: "replace $string $file || die $file" where replace and die are suitably defined functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might connect the last `exit` with a `&&`, too. When you use `;` it will execute all commands in sequential order. Commands after `&&` will execute only if the prior command ran successful, commands after `||` will execute only if the prior command did *not* run successful.

```
grep  && sed || echo "ERROR1! Exiting..." && exit
grep  && sed || echo "ERROR1! Exiting..." && exit
```

Answer (score 3):

What's this infatuation you seem to have (based on this question and the [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899214/shell-script-continues-to-run-even-after-exit-command)) with doing everything in a single line. Have you got a vertically challenged terminal device? Does your department get charged per line of code they store in the source code repository?

The phrase "I don't want to use if conditions" has no place coming out of the mouth of a sapient creature, and it's one of the most bizarre *artificial* limitations I've ever heard of. Seriously, code for *readability!*

That way, those that have to maintain your code (including yourself six months down the track) won't be cursing your name for such a bone-headed decision <sup>(a)</sup>.

The fact that you have to *ask* how to do this is indication enough that it's a bad idea. I bet you wouldn't have to ask how to do it as a multi-line, readable, maintainable `if` statement.

Feel free to downvote me - it's not as if I'm short on rep :-) I'll take that chance since there's plenty of precedent on SO for providing answers stating that the premise behind the question is not a good one. I'd also question the sanity of those that want to code operating systems in COBOL or accounting applications in 8051 machine code.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> No offence intended, though I suspect you won't be accepting this answer :-)

Comment: Why should someone (especially the OP) downvote? This is constructive and valid criticism and the your presentation makes people smile. Well at least me.

Answer (score 3):

You can run several commands using `{}`:

```
cmd1 || { echo "ERROR" ; exit 1 ; }
```

but I prefer to wrap the error handling in a function:

```
error() { # msg 
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

which makes it much more readable:

```
cmd1 || error "ERROR"
```

or how about this:

```
try() { # cmd args...
    local msg="ERROR: command failed: $@"
    "$@" || { echo "$msg" 2>&1 ; exit 1 }
}

try cmd1 arg1 arg2...
```

which gives you a nice error message, too.

If you need an explanation, that's simple as well:

```
try2() { # msg cmd args...
    local msg="ERROR: $@"
    shift # Swallow first argument
    "$@" || { echo "$msg" 2>&1 ; exit 1 }
}

try2 "Explain what the command is supposed to do" \
    cmd1 arg1 arg2...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` instead of `;`, as `;` means that the next command will be executed whether the first one worked or didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed -i~ "s/string1/string2/g" abc.txt || exit 1
sed -i~ "s/string2/string3/g" pqr.txt
```

Or if you want something more verbose:

```
function doexit
{
    echo "error " $1
    exit $1
}

sed -i~ "s/string1/string2/g" abc.txt || doexit 1
sed -i~ "s/string2/string3/g" pqr.txt
```